# set multiple variables from one awk command?

Tags: bash, awk

This is a very common script:

```
#!/bin/bash

teststr="col1 col2"

var1=`echo ${teststr} | awk '{print $1}'`
var2=`echo ${teststr} | awk '{print $2}'`

echo var1=${var1}
echo var2=${var2}
```

However I dont like this, especially when there are more fields to parse. 
I guess there should be a better way like:

(var1,var2)=`echo ${teststr} | awk '{print $1 $2}' 
(in my imagination)

Is that so?
Thanks for help to improve effeciency and save some CPU power.

Comment: `read -r a b < <(awk '{print $1, $2}' <<< "hello world")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
var=(col0 col1 col2)
echo "${var[1]}"
```

Will output:

```
col1
```

Comment: Thanks to remind me for bash arries. This is the solution. One can also write like this: var=(`echo ${blabla} | awk -F"_" '{print $1 " " $3}'`)...

Comment: Nice! Use of parentheses is key.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, but the best practice is to **use the awk way to pass variables to awk**.

**Example using shell script variables**

```
awk -v awkVar1="$scriptVar1" -v awkVar2="$scriptVar2" '<your awk code>'
```

**Example using environmental variables**

```
awk -v awkVar1=ENVIRON["ENV_VAR1"] -v awkVar2=ENVIRON["ENV_VAR2"] '<your awk code>'
```

**It's possible to use script and environmental variables at the same time**

```
awk -v awkVar1=ENVIRON["ENV_VAR1"] -v awkVar2="$scriptVar2" '<your awk code>'
```

You may find bash tricks to circumvent the awk way to do it, but it's not safe.

**Explanation and more examples**

Awk works this way, because it's a programming language by itself and has it's own way to use variables 'inside' awk statements.

By '**inside**' i mean **the part between the single quotes**.

Let's see an example, where we turn off DHCP in a config file, all done using variables in a shell script. I'm going to explain the last line of code.

The script isn't optimal, it's main purpose is to use script variables. Explaining how the script does its job is out of scope of this answer, the focus is on explaining the use of variables.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# set some variables

# set path to the config file to edit
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

# find the line number of the line to change using awk and assign it to a variable
DHCP_LINE=$(awk '/dhcp4: yes/{print FNR}' $CONFIG_FILE)

# get the number of spaces used for identation using awk and assign it to a variable
SPACES=$(awk -v awkDHCP_LINE="$DHCP_LINE" 'FNR==awkDHCP_LINE {print match($0,/[^ ]|$/)-1}' $CONFIG_FILE)

# find DHCP setting and turn it off if needed
awk -v awkDHCP_LINE="$DHCP_LINE" -v awkSPACES="$SPACES" 'FNR==awkDHCP_LINE {sub("dhcp4: yes", "dhcp4: no")}' $CONFIG_FILE
```

Let's break this last line up to pieces for explanation.

> awk -v awkDHCP_LINE="$DHCP_LINE" -v awkSPACES="$SPACES"

This part above assigns the value of `DHCP_LINE` script variable to the `awkDHCP_LINE` awk variable and the the value of `SPACES` script variable to the `awkSPACES`awk variable.

Please note, that the `SPACES` variable is passed to awk for the sake of showing how to pass multiple variables only; the awk command doesn't process it.

> 'FNR==awkDHCP_LINE {sub("dhcp4: yes", "dhcp4: no")}'

This one above is the '**inside**' part of awk where the variable(s) passed to awk can be used.

> $CONFIG_FILE

This part is **outside** awk, a generic script variable is used to specify the file that should be processed.

I hope this clears things a bit :)

Note: if you have lots of variables to pass, the solution provided by @potong may prove a better approach depending on your use case.

Comment: Is this answer about how to pass variables in to awk? The question is about how to assign values from the output of awk to bash variables.

Answer (score 0):

Bash has Array Support, We just need to supply values dynamically :)

```
function test_set_array_from_awk(){

    # Note : -a is required as declaring array
    let -a myArr;

    # Hard Coded Valeus 
    # myArr=( "Foo" "Bar" "other" );
    # echo "${myArr[1]}" # Print Bar 

    # Dynamic values 
    myArr=( $(echo "" | awk '{print "Foo"; print "Bar"; print "Fooo-And-Bar"; }') );

    # Value @index 0 
    echo "${myArr[0]}" # Print Foo

    # Value @index 1
    echo "${myArr[1]}" # Print Bar 

    # Array Length 
    echo ${#myArr[@]}  # Print 3 as array length 

    # Safe Reading with Default value 
    echo "${myArr[10]-"Some-Default-Value"}" # Print Some-Default-Value
    echo "${myArr[10]-0}"    # Print 0  
    echo "${myArr[10]-''}"   # Print ''
    echo "${myArr[10]-}"     # Print nothing

    # With Dynamic Index 
    local n=2
    echo "${myArr["${n}"]-}" # Print Fooo-And-Bar

}

# calling test function
test_set_array_from_awk
```

Bash Array Documentation : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shell `set` builtin to place whitespace seperated (or more accurately, `IFS` seperated) into the variables `$1`, `$2` and so on:

```
#!/bin/bash

teststr="col1 col2"
set -- $teststr
echo "$1" # col1
echo "$2" # col2
```